# How do I filter out products from certain categories from Magento search?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried adding the following on Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php, _getProductCollection()

```
 $this->_productCollection
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array('36,37'),));
```

But it came up with:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816
```

I suspected it was because it was looking for an attribute that product doesn't have "category_id" and I tried adding:

```
 $this->_productCollection
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array('36,37'),));
```

But that brings up another error:

```
Joined field with this alias is already declared"
```

What am I doing wrong?
 Is Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php the correct file to apply this overwrite?
 I just want it to apply to the search results i.e catalogsearch/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try Using 
** ->addCategoriesFilter($category);** instead of ->addAttributeToFilter(

It works for me :)

Comment: I tried that, but ->addCategoriesFilter($category) only filters one category and it adds a category, instead of removing. I need to remove several categories instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here there is a small change required

->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('nin'=>'36'))

category_ids instead of category_id ;)

Comment: Hi Sandeep

This change brought an SQL error:
Unknown column 'e.category_ids' in 'where clause'

Comment: Use ->printLogQuery(true) and paste the sql over here 
let me check

Comment: It was too large for a comment. Please see below

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL causing the error when I use addAttributeToFilter('category_ids')

SELECT `e`.*, `search_result`.`relevance`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='2677'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' WHERE (`e`.`category_ids` NOT IN('36,37')) AND (`e`.`category_ids` NOT IN('36,37')) ORDER BY `relevance` desc LIMIT 20

Answer (score 0):

Well i got it working . try this:

```
/*my rand products here*/
$products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$products->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1);
$this->setProductCollection($products);

/*this made the trick*/
$array_ids_cat=array();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id){
    $array_ids_cat[]=array('finset'=>$cat_id);
}

$_products = $this->getProductCollection()->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')                                            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $array_ids_cat  );
```